# How i will get aspx as popover using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
window.open('ProofofInsurance.aspx?ClubId=' + ClubId, '',
    'width=600,height=430,left=230,top=100'); 
return false;
```

I got popover window using above code but I have to use as jquery function?

```
 ShowPopup('MailQuote.aspx', 'Quote Link', 90, 90, 'AppNo=' + 
     getParameterByName("id") + '&Mode=' + p_Mode + '&program=' + 
     getParameterByName("program"));
```

Show popup function is defined as:

```
function ShowPopup(p_URL, p_Header, p_AlertWidth, p_AlertHeight, p_QueryString) {
    var width = ($(window).width() * p_AlertWidth) / 100;
    var height = ($(window).height() * p_AlertHeight) / 100;

    //for smaller screens width and height will be full screen size
    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();
    }
    //background-image: url('../_gfx/PopUpGrd.jpg')
    //$("<style>.ui-widget-header {   background-color: #5F9DD8 };border: 0px solid #aaaaaa;background: rgba(155, 144, 144, 0)</style>").appendTo('body');
    //$("<style>.ui-widget-content {  border: 1px solid #2D9CE6").appendTo('body');

    $("<div id='dialog' title='" + p_Header + "' style='overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;border:0px solid #fff;'><iframe style='overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;border:0px solid #fff;' src='" + p_URL + "?" + p_QueryString + "'></iframe></div>").dialog({
        width: width, height: height, modal: true, close: function (ev, ui) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href;
            overlay = $('<div></div>').prependTo('body').attr('id', 'divOverlayLoading');
            center($('#Loadingdialog'));
            $('#Loadingdialog').show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please tidy up the code in your question so people can follow what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a fresh code to open a pop-up from asp.net page using pure jquery & css.

First the Css, Popup.css:

```
.modal-backdrop {
       background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       display: none;
   }
   .modal {
       width: 500px;
       position: absolute;
       top: 25%;
       z-index: 1020;
       background-color: #FFF;
       border-radius: 6px;
       display: none;
   }
   .modal-header {
       background-color: #333;
       color: #FFF;
       border-top-right-radius: 5px;
       border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   }
   .modal-header h3 {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
       line-height: 40px;
   }
   .modal-header h3 .close-modal {
       float: right;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #FFF;
   }
   .modal-footer {
       background-color: #F1F1F1;
       padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
       line-height: 40px;
       text-align: right;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
       border-top: solid 1px #CCC;
   }
   .modal-body {
       padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
   }
```

Inside the Parent Page add the following code. It also adds your popup control but keeps it hidden. Note the src which is set to Temp.aspx for testing.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_open" runat="server" Text="Open Login page" CssClass="openModal" />
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Login <a class="close-modal" href="#">&times;</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <iframe style=" width:100%; height: 100%;" id="ifrm" src="Temp.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
     <asp:Button ID="btn_close" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="modalOK close-modal" />
</div>
```

Now again, in the parent page, at the very top add the css reference and the jQuery code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/PopUp.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        modalPosition();
        $(window).resize(function () {
            modalPosition();
        });
        $('.openModal').click(function (e) {
            $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeIn('fast');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.close-modal').click(function (e) {
            $('.modal, .modal-backdrop').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
    function modalPosition() {
        var width = $('.modal').width();
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var x = (pageWidth / 2) - (width / 2);
        $('.modal').css({ left: x + "px" });
    }
</script>
```